# Number of valid assignments of 1 to 9 in abc + def = ghi?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am looking for help on a kids math problem I found: 
“Given numbers 1 to 9, place them in the sum `abc + def = ghi`, 
such that each number is used once and the sum is correct. (e.g. a=2, d=6, g=8,  etc.)”

After playing around for a bit I found a couple of solutions, however I feel like I have not “solved” the problem. 
Now I would like to *count* all possible solutions. I could trivially write a computer program to generate all valid solutions, however I would still remain without the adequate mathematical intuition.  
How would you approach this problem from a pen-and-paper perspective ?

Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions.

Comment: A bunch of casework involving considering the parity of the values, and the existence of carry overs.